# Codeacademy: Averages

Tags: python

I'm working on this problem from Code Academy and what I want the code to do is to return the tests, quizzes and homework averages for each student separately.

This is what I have for the code for right now.

It says this error message 'invalid syntax' and more.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]

def average(some):
    return sum(some)/len(some)

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
def get_class_average(students):
    for student in students:
         total += get_average(student)
    return float(total) / len(students)
```

Comment: the traceback tells you line numbers

Comment: -1 for lack for effort.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `get_average()` (I assume you mean `average()` here) with a dictionary, not a list. So `sum()` won't work with it. In order to get the actual homework or quiz or test list, you have to do `total += get_average(student['homework'])`.

You're also missing a `}` after your tyler dictionary. This will make python think the `def average` bit is part of the dictionary, but it can't be, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you missed a curly before the

```
def average...
```

It should be

```
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
def average ...
```

Also in `get_average_class` you don't say what `get_average` is. I'd assume it's something that uses `average` that you've omitted, but if you meant average than you've got a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
def average(some):
    return sum(some)/len(some)

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
def get_class_average(students):
    for student in students:
         total += get_average(student)
    return float(total) / len(students)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close off your braces before the `average` function.